# webex the audio device is unaccessable now

Tags: java, cisco, webex

I have 64 bit ubuntu 14.04. and my problem while executing webex is I get this message.

```
the audio device is unaccessable now.
```

thus, no sound.

to resolve this
I followed the steps as described [here](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2014/02/07/webex-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10/)
after installing some packages I also eneded with
this line in check.txt

```
libjawt.so => not found
```

after entering this:

```
apt-file search libjawt.so
```

I get this list:

```
gcc-snapshot: /usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcj-4.9.0-15/libjawt.so
gcc-snapshot: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-snap-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
gcj-4.8-jre: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
libgcj14-awt: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/lib/libjawt.so
libgcj14-awt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so
libgcj14-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcj-4.8-14/libjawt.so
openjdk-6-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-6-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-7-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
openjdk-7-jre-headless: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so
```

observing that
libgcj14-awt package is in the list above
I tried to install the 32 version of libgcj14-awt using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgcj14-awt:i386
```

but I get the reply:

```
libgcj14-awt:i386 is already the newest version
```

but still after removing .webex directory and executing once more webex application I get this line again in check.txt:

```
libjawt.so => not found
```

so I thought maybe to install gcj-4.8-jre:i386 (that also in the list above) using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcj-4.8-jre:i386
```

but I get this reply:

```
gcj-4.8-jre:i386 : Depends: gcj-4.8-jre-headless:i386 (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so what should I do next to get sound in webex?